# OpenCV can not get the right max and min values of Mat

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am trying to find the max and min value of Mat,but I can not get the right answer.I got the right max and min values that maxValue==2.2222 and minValue==0.0810810 in MATLAB.But I got other result that maxValue==8.988e+307 and minValue==0.0232549 in OpenCV.In OpenCV,I used two methods,std::max_element() and minMaxLoc(),and got the same result.
My code(OpenCV):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

#include <cv.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#define PI 3.1415926

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img=imread("test.jpg");
    if(!img.data)
    {
        cout<<"Error:Reading image!"<<endl;
    }

    img.convertTo(img,CV_64FC3);

    vector<Mat> rgb;
    split( img, rgb);
    Mat B=rgb[0];
    Mat G=rgb[1];
    Mat R=rgb[2];

    Mat x,X,y,Y;
    divide(R,G,x,1);
    divide(B,G,y,1);
    log(x,X);
    log(y,Y);

    Mat projectedPoint;
    projectedPoint=X.mul(cos(PI))+Y.mul(sin(PI));

    Mat imgGrey;
    exp(projectedPoint,imgGrey);

    //method 1;
    cout<<"max_element=="<<*max_element(imgGrey.begin<double>(),imgGrey.end<double>())<<endl;

    //method 2;
    double imgGreyMin=0;
    double imgGreyMax=0;
    minMaxLoc(imgGrey,&imgGreyMin,&imgGreyMax,NULL,NULL);
    cout<<"minValue=="<<imgGreyMin<<" maxValue=="<<imgGreyMax<<endl;

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

MATLAB:

```
clc;
clear;
format long;
img=imread('test.jpg');
img=im2double(img);
R=img(:,:,1);
G=img(:,:,2);
B=img(:,:,3);
X=log(R./G);
Y=log(B./G);

W=size(X,1);
L=size(X,2);

projectedPoint=ones(W,L);
projectedPoint=X*cosd(180)+Y*sind(180);
imgGrey=exp(projectedPoint);

minValue=min(min(imgGrey));
maxValue=max(max(imgGrey));
```

Comment: In MATLAB,the data type is double.

Comment: 1e307 looks suspiciously like a NaN/Inf which probably comes from the zeros in the green image channel. What does `isnan(imgGrey)` and `isinf(imgGrey)` in matlab give?

Comment: You're right,some elements of imgGrey were NaN,but when I checked those elements in opencv,the result show that they were not NaN.@mars

Comment: can you provide `test.jpg`?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3sHkQBo48mhLWplNHlqakw3bzA/edit?usp=sharing I almost solved the problem,but there are still have some small questions,maybe you could provide me with better solutions.@Micka

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem is not in minMaxLoc, i.e. when your function reach this point imgGrey indeed has such large values. This may happen if one of G pixels is equal to zero (I guess MATLAB treats such cases differently).

On the side note, I am not really understand what this line is for:

```
projectedPoint=X.mul(cos(PI))+Y.mul(sin(PI));
```

cos(PI) is -1. sin(PI) is 0. You could just write:

```
projectedPoint = -X;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I got the position of max in matlab,and I use the position to get the right value in opencv,so I think that ingGrey has no such large value.PS:This this piece of code is part of my program,and the prototype is: `projectedPoint=X.mul(cos(theta*PI/180))+Y.mul(sin(theta*PI/180));`@Michael Burdinov

Comment: Can you check the values of all your matrices in this specific pixel (R, G, B, x, X, y, Y, projectedPoint and imgGrey)?

Comment: Both ProjectedPoint and imgGrey in opencv are the same as they are in matlab.@Michael Burdinov

Comment: Yes I understand that they are the same. I am asking what are the values of 'maximum pixel' in all the intermediate matrices?

Comment: I got the max value in imgGrey is imgGrey.at<double>(437,442) in matlab,so I can get the values of 'maximum pixel' in all the intermediate matrices in opencv,i.e.(R, G, B, X, Y, projectedPoint, imgGrey)==(9,20,3,-0.798508,-1.89712,0.798508,2.22222).

Comment: If this pixel was calculated properly that means that some other pixel was not. You can define 'Point maxLoc;' and call 'minMaxLoc(imgGrey,&imgGreyMin,&imgGreyMax,NULL,&maxLoc);'. In maxLoc you will have location of pixel with maximal value (and that location won't be (437,442)). If you get all the intermediate values in this pixel you would be able to see the problem.

Comment: It is so weird!In opencv,I got the maxValue==8.988e+307 and position is point(533,433),but when I used those lines:
    
    `double imgGreyMin=0;
     double imgGreyMax=0;
     Point minPoint,maxPoint;
     minMaxLoc(imgGrey,&imgGreyMin,&imgGreyMax,&minPoint,&maxPoint);
     cout<<imgGreyMax<<endl;
     cout<<maxPoint.x<<" "<<maxPoint.y<<endl;
     cout<<"maxValue1=="<<imgGrey.at<double>(maxPoint.x,maxPoint.y)<<endl;`

I got the maxValue1==1.02439,and it is not equal to maxValue==8.988e+307.What happened?

Comment: You should use imgGrey.at<double>(maxPoint.y,maxPoint.x) instead of imgGrey.at<double>(maxPoint.x,maxPoint.y). Notice reversed order of x and y. Or you can use imgGrey.at<double>(maxPoint) which is even better.

Comment: I found that some elements of imgGrey were NAN in matlab,but when I checked those elements using isnan() method in opencv,the result show that those elements were not NAN.For example,maxValue==8.988e+307 was NAN and NANs are ignored in matlab,but it was not NAN in opencv,so I got the wrong result.

Comment: I'm not a c++ language lawyer, but I suspect in c++ isnan(8.988e307) would return true in your case. It's just that your compiler doesn't check for it. Personally, I would rather mask out the result where the G pixel value is below a certain threshold than filter out the NaNs afterwards.